# Do I need to change the mysql.sys password

Tags: mysql, database, sql

This is probably a daft question, but do I need to change the mysql.sys password?

After doing a:

```
SELECT User,Host,Authentication_String FROM mysql.user;
```

to display the mysql users, hosts and passwords I see that the mysql.sys users password is set as follows:

```
mysql.sys | localhost | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
```

`Mysql version is 5.7.13` and am having problems finding the code to change the password for another user. (test user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change this user password.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.9, sys schema objects have a DEFINER of 'mysql.sys'@'localhost'. (Before MySQL 5.7.9, the DEFINER is 'root'@'localhost'.)
>
> Use of the dedicated mysql.sys account avoids problems that occur if a DBA renames or removes the root account.

You can use `sudo mysql_secure_installation` to set root password and other secure conf. Then use `root` user change the `mysql.sys` password. As document say, not suggest del this user.

Comment: Thanks. i sorted it out a while ago. cant remember how but I just changed the password.

Answer (score 0):

Not, you don't need to change the password for mysql.sys user, it is locked by default.

> 'mysql.sys'@'localhost': Used as the DEFINER for sys schema objects.
> Use of the mysql.sys account avoids problems that occur if a DBA
> renames or removes the root account. This account is locked so that it
> cannot be used for client connections. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-accounts.html

You can get a better explain here: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-the-purpose-of-mysql-syslocalhost-user/